# how to do load balancing on remote Actors in Akka?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

I am working in a distributed environment where I have to setup Actors in remote systems. I want to distribute the load among all the remote actors. Can anyone suggest me the best way to balance load in a cluster? My current scenario is in one remote system I have 10 actors which are running. so for example, let's say I have 3 system and systems have 10 actors and I want to balance the load among all the 30 actors.

Comment: The "best" way depends a lot on your circumstances, but the "Routing" chapter of the Akka documentation is probably interesting to you: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/routing.html

Comment: Not exactly the latest blog post, but maybe [this](http://letitcrash.com/post/29044669086/balancing-workload-across-nodes-with-akka-2) is useful.

Comment: Akka load balancer creates the internal child of an actor based on the number of the child we specify. Here in my case, I can't use any actor to process my request i want specific request to be executed by a specific actor

Comment: @stholzm the documentation does not have example explanation on balancing list of actors. They are doing load balancing by creating a pool of child actors.

Comment: Looks like cluster sharing will solve your issue. You get the functionality you want by default. Please refer the below link -  https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/cluster-sharding.html

Answer (score 3):

A good way to distribute work is by pulling it from the worker instead of centralising the decision and pushing, which can potentially overload the worker nodes if you have a higher rate of work coming in than you can actually process.

There is a sample project and tutorial showing worker actors pulling work here: https://developer.lightbend.com/guides/akka-distributed-workers-scala/